Cloudflare / X (Twitter) integration debugging
There is an integration with X (3-legged OAuth flow) which works locally with wrangler.
Once deployed to Cloudflare (Pages function), it fails on the last step - the call to /oauth/access_token fails with 500 status code and "This page is down" HTML page.
Observations:

I've printed the Authorization header, generated on Cloudflare to log, and tried to pass it to /oauth/access_token in Postman. It worked locally, so I make an assumption that the cryptography part is good.
I've used a external service to accept and print any request (including headers). Copy pasted all the headers (Authorization, Cf-*, etc) to the Postman. It worked locally, so I make an assumption that the request is good.
The first step, which is a call to /oauth/refresh_token, works on Cloudflare. The only differences compared to /oauth/access_token are passed parameters and the URL.

Only oauth-1.0a and node:crypto packages are used. Native fetch for HTTP calls.
Could you please give me some hints on debugging options I have.

beware of low-quality answers attracted by the bounty.
